# Pop-up successful message in Fancybox?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have a very long page and CF7 at the bottom. The problem is that when/if the user completes the fields and press Submit, the error or successful messages appear near the Submit button, but at the bottom, whilst the page scrolls up because of the refresh.

Is there a way I can show this message in a Fancybox pop-up/modal window, that would be closed after the user will click on it or outside?

Comment: Check out this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-response-colorbox-popup/ I hope it's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully aware of the possibilities of cf7 or your abillities to change it. But when I come across a situation like this i find it more user friendly that your page scrolls back down.
You can do this by adding an anchor to your post of the form like #contactform , so when the page refreshes to ...#form it scrolls back down. I think this will be easier to achive than to go change to plugin to have it in some modal popup.
Also when users have to change something in the form, they are already back at the form.

check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp, or just google html anchors for more info. and add the needed changes to the plugin form. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_bookmark

Comment: http://w3fools.com/ - better reference sources in this page ;)

Comment: how is this relevant?

Comment: Do you mean how much harm can be done by faulty documentation (w3schools)?

Comment: not everything is faulty, i'm just referring to the anchor tag. I'm not saying, now go and study this entire website, and use it like your bible...

Answer (score 0):

just put `[response]` at the top of your form and when the form submits and the page reloads the message will be at the top.

Comment: This is a shortcode provided by CF7, correct?

Comment: Erm, that wouldn't be helpful as the point was to avoid having the message at the top, then the question was if I can show it in a lightbox without the page jump; also, I don't think that one year ago when I've started the question the [response] code existed, or I just don't remember, not that it would have helped